# Is there any verse in the Quran about personal protection?

Tags: sunni, self-defense, protection

Are there any verses in the Quran about personal protection, any verses that says we need to avoid unnecessary harmful acts?

Answer (score 3):

Two of the popular verses that comes to mind are **Al Baqarah verse 195**:

> And spend in the way of Allah and **do not throw [yourselves] with your [own] hands into destruction [by refraining].** And do good; indeed, Allah loves the doers of good. Source: http://quran.com/2/195

and **An Nisa verse 29**:

> O you who have believed, do not consume one another's wealth unjustly but only [in lawful] business by mutual consent. **And do not kill yourselves [or one another].** Indeed, Allah is to you ever Merciful. Source: http://quran.com/4/29

Both verses are usually used as the basis for Muslim to refrain from smoking or any other harmful things.